# ROS Fuerte, rviz, NX on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: rviz, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone had any luck getting a Desktop-Full version of ROS up and running in the cloud?

I commissioned an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance, installed ROS Fuerte on it, and have been using x2go as a graphical interface to the remote machine. TurtleSim and rxgraph run fine, but rviz segfaults with the message:

```
Config file '/home/ubuntu/.rviz/config' could not be opened for reading.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On the [rviz troubleshooting page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting) I see a reference to the fact that that running rviz remotely is not possible. I also wonder if NX clients such as x2go would even support a 3D-accelerated application like rviz.

But it would be nice to run ROS Desktop in the cloud -- maybe even create an AMI for a one-click trial of ROS. Should I give up on that dream for now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49552/ros-fuerte,-rviz,-nx-on-amazon-ec2-instance/) by [isherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2938/isherman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of teams running ROS in the Cloud (even in EC2 land).

I have not seen that error, but one suggestion would be to run rviz locally and just set the ROS_MASTER_URI to the machine in the cloud (assuming that you're on a vpn or have the appropriate network config).

If you really don't want to run a local rviz, I guess another option could be to use Xnest.. it will be slow, but it's one means of getting to the true issue that you're facing.

On a possibly related tip, I'd also recommend that you try using [Xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html) or something similar, and create a display that you use to render the remote simulation environment. I've never used x2go, but I'm wary of rendering the desktop over the (inter)network.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2938/isherman/) on 2012-12-02**:
Thank you, good to hear it should be possible. I'll give it a try with standard X-forwarding to try and get to the root of the segfault.

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-07-26**:
@isherman were you able to run rviz on AWS?